# Null Pointer Exception Adding a Toolbar

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jtoolbar

I am trying to add a toolbar to my program but when I add the code, I am getting a nullpointerexception, anyone know why this may be happening?

```
public JButton makeButton(String imageName,
        String toolTipText) {
//Look for the image.
String imgLocation = "images/" + imageName + ".jpg";
URL imageURL = assignment3.class.getResource(imgLocation);

//Create and initialize the button.
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
button.addActionListener(this);

button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageURL));

return button;
}
```

The exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at assignment3.assignment3.makeButton(assignment3.java:331)
```

Comment: Without knowing what line the NPE is on or seeing more code, it'll be a bit hard to figure it out. My guess is that imageURL is null.

Comment: In which line is the exception thrown? A stack trace is more than useful.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at assignment3.assignment3.makeButton(assignment3.java:331)
This one is the "button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageURL));
 at assignment3.assignment3.<init>(assignment3.java:294)
This one is above where I try to use the method "btnAnswer = makeButton("answer", "Answer The Question");"

Comment: It tells you the file and line number.  What more do you need?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something completely trivial.

Comment: @Kalkrin The imageURL is null.

Answer (score 3):

> "I am getting a nullpointerexception, anyone know why this may be happening?"
>
> `java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon`

You're getting a `nullpointerexception` because the URL is null, due to a bad path, and you're passing a null URL to the `ImageIcon`

You need another `/` in front of the path

```
String imgLocation = "/images/" + imageName + ".jpg";
                      ^
```

And you `images` needs to be directly a child of the `src`

```
ProjectRoot
          src
              images
                   someimage.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I got it working and it was just a pathing error, I never had to add the extra slash. Oddly enough, I figured it would be the src folder too but I actually had to put the images folder in the bin.

Comment: @Kalkim you should _not_ have to explicitly put the `images` into the `bin`. It should get copied from the `src` to the `bin` when you build. You will also find that if your package uses layers dirs like `com.mypackage` you _will_ need the `/`. You don't need it if it's only one layer like `mypackage`, but you might as well make a habit of it. The `/` will work for both scenarios.

Comment: If the `images` does _not_ get automatically copied to the `bin` then you have a problem and you need to check your configuration. And again you shouldn't have to mess with the `bin` at all. Actually I recommend to not ever touch the `bin`. It should be synced with the `src`